# How can i solve this in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I need to set DX register to -5 but just by using logical operators(except NOT), shift/rotate operators and NEG, no other instructions allowed(no assigning of constants).

Comment: What CPU? All questions regarding assembly should really be clear on this, at least.

Comment: _"using logical operators"_ `XOR DX,DX` / `OR DX,-5`. There, finished.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sure, I can guess too, but isn't it better if the question is at least *somewhat* precise?

Comment: 8086 and no Michael you cant just use that, its more tricky than that, you have to use the flags i guess...

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are 100% certain that there simply doesn't exist another CPU with a register called "DX"?

Comment: @user3293380: Based on what you've told us in your question it would be perfectly fine to use what I suggested in my comment. The question will remain unanswerable until you tell us the full set of conditions (like the _exact_ set of instructions / operands that are allowed).

Comment: Ok lets exclude constants for logical operators.... all logical except not and without using constants , shif/rotate constants allowed, and neg

Comment: @Eric Postpischil -5 in DX(32bits) register would be equal to FFFBh, the initial content would be 0, the key to this is how to get one bits in dx with the conditions mentioned above...

Comment: Maybe i should try to force CF to be 1 using the instructions allowed and i cant seem to find out how, maybe this isn't even possible that's why i'm asking you guys.After that i would use rcr instruction to rotate with carry.

Comment: Shift - SAL,SAR,SHR,SHL  Rotate - RCL,ROR,RCR,ROL ALL logical operators except NOT and NEG is it possible with these? As a separate question is there a way to pass the value of zero flag to a register?

Comment: I'm presuming logical operators means `OR`, `AND` `XOR` and `NEG` (as we're not allowed `NOT`), and that the add & subtract family are arithmetic not logical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible unless we assume some register contains a non-zero value. Proof:

Per *Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual*, March 2013, the logical instructions (5.1.4) are AND, OR, XOR, and NOT, and the shift and rotate instructions (5.1.5) are SAR, SHR, SAL/SHL, SHRD, SHLD, ROR, ROL, RCR, and RCL. Per the problem statement, NOT is excluded but NEG is included.

Inspection of these instructions, excluding NOT, shows that none of them will produce a non-zero result in a register or the carry flag if the input registers and carry flag are all zeros.

We can reasonably assume the stack pointer is not zero in any normal ABI. This allows us to produce -5:

- If DX is not known to be zero, XOR it with itself to set it to zero.
- Use OR to move the stack pointer to another register.
- Apply NEG on the new register.  This sets CF.
- Apply RCL on DX (no explicit shift amount, default one bit). This produces 1 in DX.
- Apply NEG, SHL, ROL, ROL on DX. This manipulates the bits to produce -5.

Comment: I have +1'd, but I think you need to clear DX before your third step; OP did not provide (in the question) it was zero on entry. Can you really `OR` `SP` into a new register but not `IP`?

Comment: @abligh: OP stated in a comment that DX is initially zero. If not, XOR DX with itself to set it to zero. The instruction pointer (EIP and IP) is not directly accessible on IA-32. Intel 64 makes it accessible as RIP, but I figured a question about the DX register should not count on Intel 64 features.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming use of *any* constant is banned.

How about (Intel format):

```
XOR DX, DX       # DX=0
STC              # DX=0, carry flag set
RCL DX, DX       # DX=1
ROL DX, DX       # DX=2
STC              # DX=2, carry flag set
RCL DX, DX       # DX=5
NEG DX           # DX=-5
```

I can't immediately think of a neat way to do this without `STC`. You'd have to use some operator (other than `NOT`) to set a register to something other than `0` without any constants being used. My disgusting way would be something like (and my 80x86 is rusty)

```
XOR AX, AX      # Now we know IP is not zero, i.e. at least one bit is 1
XOR BX, BX
OR AX, IP
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX
ROL AX, AX
OR BX, AX        # Now we know BX=0xFFFF, as the bit that was 1 has been put
                 # in each of the 16 bits
XOR DX, DX       # DX=0
RCL BX, BX       # DX=0, carry flag set
RCL DX, DX       # DX=1
ROL DX, DX       # DX=2
RCL BX, BX       # DX=2, carry flag set
RCL DX, DX       # DX=5
NEG DX           # DX=-5
```

Comment: OR AX, IP doesn't exit, as far as I remember.

Comment: you can do `xor ax, ax` to reset CF, then `pushf`, `pop ax`, `neg ax`, `push ax`, `popf` and you've got CF = 1. The rest is easy.

Comment: No you can't use `pushf` and `popf` because he says no other instructions.

Comment: The OP mentioned that immediate shift amounts are allowed and that the initial value of `DX` is 0, so the calculation can be reduced to 3 instructions (maybe less?).

Comment: OP did not say (in the question) the initial value of `DX` is 0, though that's obviously easy to achieve. Without using SP or IP to introduce 1's set bits, and without using an instruction which is by its nature arithmetic rather than logical (I'm avoiding saying it in case it's the answer), I am a bit puzzled.

Comment: No you cant use push and pop just specifically what i wrote in my previous comment, so is this even possible?

Comment: @user3293380 it would be quite useful to know what you consider the 'logical operators' - i.e. to list the available instructions. There is an operator that I think would be very useful here that I don't think is a logical operator, but perhaps you do.

Comment: @eric-postpischil 's answer is better than mine (here) as he's realised `NEG` sets the carry flag for any non-zero register, whereas I worked the hard way to produce a something with a known 2 top bits set so I could `rcl` them in.